# How to remove square brackets [ ] from stored Int/String retrieved using JSON (Swift)?

Tags: ios, json, swift

In the following snippet of code I am retrieving some Int values from an API call.

I want to use these values to update a couple of UILables on my app.

```
if let dict = json?["Stats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    self.tempTotalWins = [dict["totalWins"]! as! Int]
    self.tempTotalDraws = [dict["totalDraws"]! as! Int]
    self.totalWins = String(describing: self.tempTotalWins)
    self.totalDraws = String(describing: self.tempTotalDraws)
    print (self.tempTotalWins)
    self.wonLabel.text = self.totalWins!
    self.drawnLabel.text = self.totalDraws!
}
```

This is currently outputting and updating the labels as `[1]` and `[3]`.

How do I remove the `[ ]` so it just prints the number `1` and `3`?

Comment: This now prints, `Optional(1)`...  I placed a ! to unwrap print(self.tempTotalWins!) also

Comment: Just remove the brackets!   `...TotalWins = --> [  dict ... as! Int] <--  ` and you are using too many exclamation marks.

Comment: If you don't want the values in an array, why are you putting them in an array?

Comment: @Paulw11 because I don't know what I'm doing, frankly!  I'm new to this... With "Stats" being an array I didn't know how to get the values I wanted out into anything else.  As for the brackets - Xcode keeps putting them in, otherwise I get a red exclamation

Comment: @RDowns Learn the basics of the language! Just copy&paste code and having no clue what the code is doing is pretty annoying, isn't it?

Comment: it is.  I learn best by doing though - so I'm building an app based on the principles that i'm likely going to need and use in further apps.  I do try to then understand the reasons for why my code didn't work and others' does to help me learn.  Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets is noted as `Array` and that is created by you, in this line `[dict["totalWins"]! as! Int]` you have initialized `self.tempTotalWins` as array of `Int`. If you want only first object then you can get it like this.

```
if let total_Wins = dict["totalWins"] as? Int, let total_Draws = dict["totalDraws"] as? Int
    self.totalWins = String(total_Wins)
    self.totalDraws = String(total_Draws)
}
```

Comment: for your solution and explaining where I am going wrong.  However, I get this-  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: It's failing on the first if let statement when I `print (self.totalWins!)`

Comment: According the code the in question the value of `totalWins` is a single `Int` rather than an array, otherwise the code would already crash in the second line.

Comment: @vadian as I understand it yes that is correct.  I thought I may have placed the single Int in a single value array... but yes there is only 1 value contained in totalWins

Comment: @vadian Thanks for correcting me, Edited answer for that.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think understand where I was going wrong.